Iterate through JSON Dictionary using C#
I want to iterate through a JSON file of this kind, using C#, and compare if the response is the same as the expected response.
Json
file:
{
   "request": "AAA",
   "response": "BBB",
   "expected_response": "BBB"
}{
   "request": "CCC",
   "response": "DDD",
   "expected_response": "DDD"
}{
   "request": "EEE",
   "response": "FFF",
   "expected_response": "GGG"
}{
   "request": "HHH",
   "response": "III",
   "expected_response": "III"
}{
   "request": "LLL",
   "response": "YYY",
   "expected_response": "UUU"
}

To me it would make sense to do something like this:
public class Letters
{
    public string request { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string expectedResponse { get; set; }
}

var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path/to/json/file.json");

var letters_requests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Letters>(json);

foreach (var letter in letters_requests)
{
    if(letter.response == letter.expectedResponse)
        // do something
}

However, it get the following error:
foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type 'Letters' because 'Letters' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator' .
Can someone explain me how can I achieve what I want? I'm really new to C#
Thank you

Does your file contain outer brackets [ and ]?  Or is it exactly as shown?

At the moment, it would be invalid JSON even with [] as there are no commas between the objects. But (assuming the JSON is genuinely an array) it looks like you should really be declaring a class called Letter (singular) and then deserializing to a List<Letter> or similar.

If your file does not contain outer brackets and comma delimiters, it's not a proper JSON file, it's actually similar to a Newline-delimited JSON file.  To read that, see Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing.  Does that answer your question?

If you want all the Letter objects in a List<Letter>, see this answer by Evk to Deserialize multiple json objects from a stream using Newtonsoft Json.  I agree with Jon Skeet about renaming Letters to Letter by the way.

Here is a demo of the answer to Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing being used to read your NDJSON file: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xIcQbX.  Do note you also need to add [JsonProperty("expected_response")] to public string expectedResponse { get; set; }.  Closing as a duplicate.

Your Json file is incorrect, if a list of objects is stored there, then it should look like this:
[
  {
    "request": "AAA",
    "response": "BBB",
    "expected_response": "BBB"
  },
  {
    "request": "CCC",
    "response": "DDD",
    "expected_response": "DDD"
  },
  {
    "request": "EEE",
    "response": "FFF",
    "expected_response": "GGG"
  },
  {
    "request": "HHH",
    "response": "III",
    "expected_response": "III"
  },
  {
    "request": "LLL",
    "response": "YYY",
    "expected_response": "UUU"
  }
]

And deserialization should be like this:
var letters_requests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Letters>>(json);


You are trying to deserialise a collection of Letters objects to a single Letters object. From your code intention you are trying to parse all the objects in your json file.
Change your code to something like this: (assuming you want a List<Letters>)
var letters_requests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Letters>>(json);

You can also use Letters[] if this suits you more.

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Letters>>(json); does not work with with the file contents shown in the question, it results in an exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Letters]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly..  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/6hh26Y.
